# is there a way to caa .nls file in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, nls

please I have a notepad file saved with .nls, how do I call it to my NetLogo ... anybody help me with the code

```
globals [
    letter_E
];
```

for declaring global var

patches-own  [number]
;patch var

to setup
    clear-all
    setup-patches
    reset-ticks
end

ask patches
[
    set plabel =
    set-pcolor = black
    set-patch-size = 10
]

to setup-letter_E

;set your cordinates

ask (patch-set patch 0 0)
    [set pcolor 0]

ask (patch-set patch 0 1)
    [set pcolor 1]

ask (patch-set patch 1 1)
    [set pcolor 2]

ask (patch-set patch 1 2)
    [set pcolor 3]

ask (patch-set patch 2 2)
    [set pcolor 4]

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.  You can copy and paste the code from the .nls file to the Code tab of the NetLogo model, or you can use the `__includes` feature of NetLogo.  If your .nls file is named (for instance) `mycode.nls`, you can put at the top of your NetLogo model code

```
__includes["mycode.nls"]
```

(There are two underscores in front of "includes".)  If you check out `__inlcudes` in the NetLogo dictionary, you will see that you can include more than one .nls file.  The files should be in the same directory as your model. When you do that, the NetLogo Code tab will have a drop-down list of "Included Files" and you will find "mycode.nls" there.

All that said, the code you have in the .nls file will not run as is. There are a number of errors. But that is a different question.

Comment: `__includes` requires square brackets, not parens:  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#includes

Comment: Oops. Edit made. Thanks Jasper.

Comment: Thanks bro... it really helps 